# API Authorization token error

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I'm trying to use the [Survey API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/).

When I try and use the form online to request an *Authorization token* I get a 
 error message.

> Invalid or missing access token" error message.

The form to test the API calls also asks for a Client Secret code but yet it auto fills the box with the API Key.
Any help here would be nice.

I'm not sure if this is a bug on Survey Monkey's end either in the API or the form that tests the API.

Answer (score 2):

You should have received a reply to this via email but I wanted to ensure this was answered here in case anyone else is having the same issue.

- There was a bug on our API console preventing an access token being issued, this is now fixed.
- The access token has to be copied into the "Authorization" parameter in the format "bearer ".  e.g. if your access token is 'fdhjfu3cc8ss=', make sure the Authorization parameter has "bearer fdhjfu3cc8ss=" in it (with no quotes).  Note that you need to use the Access Token returned, not the Authorization Code.